# How to prove the performance, Big Omega ,of building a binary heap using recursive method is Ω(nlog(n))

Tags: heaps, performance, big-o-notation

We can learn the big-O of building a binary heap using recursive method is O(n log n) from wiki
"This approach, called Williams’ method after the inventor of binary heaps, is easily seen to run in O(n log n) time: it performs n insertions at O(log n) cost each.[a]"  we can also know if we build the heap using other methods. the big O could be better. Where should we begin if we would like to prove that the  performance, Big Omega ,of building a binary heap using recursive method is  Ω(nlog(n)), which is same as Big-O?

insert method from wiki

> To add an element to a heap we must perform an up-heap operation (also
>   known as bubble-up, percolate-up, sift-up, trickle-up, swim-up,
>   heapify-up, or cascade-up), by following this algorithm:
>
> Add the element to the bottom level of the heap. Compare the added
>   element with its parent; if they are in the correct order, stop. If
>   not, swap the element with its parent and return to the previous step

then we have the buildheap as

```
buildheap((1,1),(,)) 
   if n==1: 
      return [(1,1)] 
return insert(( ,),buildheap((1,1),...(−1,−1))
```

Comment: The first step is to define the problem formally. Are you trying to prove a lower bound on the worst case complexity of a *particular* algorithm ("recursive method")? Perhaps you're looking for a lower bound for an algorithmic task ("building a binary heap")? In the former case, you should describe the algorithm, and in the latter, the problem you are interested in.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, is this more clear ?

Comment: You need to give an input on which the algorithm takes $\Omega(n\log n)$ steps.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your heap is a max-heap: a parent should be larger than its children. Consider what happens when you call `buildheap` with the numbers $1,\ldots,n$ in that order. Each time you add a new element to the bottom level of the heap, and the `heapify` procedure diffuses it all the way to the root. Since element $k$ is put at level $\Theta(\log k)$, inserting the $k$'th element takes time $\Theta(\log k)$. Overall, `buildheap` takes time $\Theta(\log 1 + \cdots + \log n) = \Theta(\log n!) = \Theta(n\log n)$.

Comment: can you give a bit reasoning on " Since element  is put at level Θ(log)", why is Θ, not O, and  why log k? Θ means lower bound, why not just Θ(1), always at the right place ?

Comment: Big Theta isn't (just) a lower bound. I suggest reviewing the various notations of asymptotic analysis.

Comment: Element 1 is put at level 0. Elements 2,3 are put at level 1. Elements 4,5,6,7 are put at level 2. More generally, elements $2^d,\ldots,2^{d+1}-1$ are put at level $d$.

Comment: yes Big Theta  gives both lower bound and upper bound. still "Since element  is put at level Θ(log)" is not convincing enough. it seems like to me just a statement without any proofs/reasoning , (or I just missed something obvious)

Comment: Yes, that’s on purpose. It’s your exercise, after all.